# Wiring Raspberry PI GPIO pins to a remote to simulate a button press?

Tags: controller, raspberry-pi, hardware, gpio, infrared

I have some lights that you turn can on by using a small IR remote. My first idea was that I would be able to wire my RPI GPIO pins to the button and turn then pin on and off to simulate a button press but have had no luck at all.

I tried by connecting the ground of the Pi to the ground of the remote and then connected the GPIO pins to a 330 ohm resistor and then to the button with the tracer wire connected to the chip on the remote.

Is it possible to wire it up this way to simulate a button press to turn on my lights? I have heard some people said you use an opto-isolator but don't understand how to connect this to the PI and the remote?

Here are some pictures of the remote.

[image: Controller front]
[image: Controller Back]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about wiring, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's talk about what an OptoIsolator is.

### [What is an OptoIsolator?](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/optoisolator)

Excerpt:
An optoisolator (also known as optical coupler, optocoupler and opto-isolator) is a semiconductor device that uses a short optical transmission path to transfer an electrical signal between circuits or elements of a circuit, while keeping them electrically isolated from each other. These components are used in a wide variety of communications, control and monitoring systems that use light to prevent electrical high voltage from affecting a lower power system receiving a signal.

### OptoIsolator Diagram

[image: OptoIsolator Diagram]

### OptoIsolator Device

[image: OptoIsolator Device]

### OptoIsolator Schematic

[image: OptoIsolator Schematic]

### Ok, so how does this help me?

So an OptoIsolator is kind of like a relay except it doesn't rely on electromagnets. Instead it often relies on infrared light transmitter (sends light) and a photoresistor (to detect light) on opposite ends of each other.

When the infrared is powered, it shines light on the photoresistor which then allows voltage to pass through the two wires on the receiving end. The devices are great for isolating electronics from one another to avoid damage and work ideal in low power environments where a relay maybe overkill.

### How can I use it?

Essentially you connect the transmitter end to your RaspberryPI, and the receiver end to your remote (you will need to desolder a button and wire up the OptoIsolator's receiver in it's place).

When your RaspberryPI fires up the transmitter by enabling/turning on the GPIO pin which it is attached to, that will in turn "press" the button on the receiving side of the OptoIsolator. Keep in mind for as long as the RaspberryPI keeps it's GPIO pin high that the button will be held, so you may need to work on getting the timing right for this device.

Comment: So two of the OptoIsolator pins would go where the button was and the and then a third to a gpio pin (will I need a resistor?) and where would the 4th go? Sorry I am clueless when it comes to electronics XD

Comment: No, technically two pins will go on the transmitter side (1 pin on GPIO pin, 1 pin on GND). On the receiver you would do the same for the button (1 pin on + and one on -). The two devices are never physically wired together with an OptoIsolator even though both are using it. Physically they are each wired to a electrically different and separate part of it.

Comment: I added a schematic image to help clarify the pinout in a single optoisolator.

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense now :D, how will I know which is + and - ?

Comment: Use a multimeter to check. The '+' side will have power if the device is powered, when the button is pressed it closes the connection with the '-' side which completes the circuit.

Comment: Thanks :D would something like this be okay? [link](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/low-current-opto-coupler-cy94c)

Comment: Yes, there are dozens of manufactures of these. Make sure you follow both the specifications (some use different voltages or have lower or higher operating requirements) and the schematics for whichever you use as the pins are for different chips (even of the same type) are sometimes in different positions.

Comment: Also, you put a resistor in the schematics can I just use the 330 ohm that I tried before?

Comment: I think 330 is good because the transmitter for the optoisolator is equivalent to an led. https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/physical-computing-guide/worksheet/

Comment: Okay great! Thanks for the help I'll give this a go!